# How to send data using POST method from ASP page to PHP page

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I have few asp controls (textboxes and checkboxes) on my asp.NET page. There is also a submit button that sends them back to me.

I can't use clear html form (without asp controls) because I want to validate data before sending it to the outside server (js validation wouldn't be enough in this case).

Is there any way and place (eg. OnClick button event) to programically create POST data packet and send it to an outside php page?

Thanks.

Comment: You will probably want to look into `CURL` for ASP to PHP transfer

Comment: If you want an HTML to PHP POST without leaving the page the AJAX is your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to construct an HTTP POST request to another page/site.

```
using(var client = new WebClient()){
    var postData = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    postData.Add("name1", "val1");
    postData.Add("name2", "val2");
    byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://www.somesite.com/someform.php", "POST", postData);
    var responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

Comment: I'm worried it will not redirect me to the php page and that is required.

Comment: If you want to redirect, use Response.Redirect().

Comment: But this will make an additional request (without the post data I've just sent).

Comment: Yes it will. Are you saying you want the data sent to you first, but you want the user to be sent to the PHP site all in one go? If so, that's just not possible. Perhaps you can display the response from the PHP site in an iframe so it appears that the user has been transferred to the other site?